# Handling multiple user tokens in kubernetes + node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, kubernetes

currently I have a digitalocean kubernetes cluster with a mongodb replica and a node.js connected to it. I must store for every user on my platform their stripe api token but I don't think inserting it in plain text inside mongodb is a good solution. Maybe I can use a kubernetes for every stripe token and save in the db only the environment pointing to the secret, the problem is that every time I add a secret I must restart all pods, so it's not a good solution. I want to know if are there more stable solutions for production environments

Answer (score 2):

There is no such built-in kubernetes feature. You can write a controller, which watch changes in secret and rolling update ta pod. There is an open source repo [reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader), which might help.

Comment: the problem is that I can't restart the pods every time a secret is added or removed because is not ideal for performance, I just need a secure way to store users credentials that I can't hash

Comment: You can store your secret in [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) to store your secret